# Comparing database table field values, with two different table in single database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am  learning php, so I want to create database and website using php, mysql, bootstrap and javascript.

First my requirement is to display all channels list with name and price with check box option in browser.

I have created two tables in database:

```
table-1(Allchannel list)
id,
channel name,
cost,
category.

table-2(broadcast packs)
id ,
channel name,
pack name,
cost,
broadcast pack name.
```

After selecting interested channels by user/customer:

1) I want to compare those selected channels with Broadcast pack table

2) if selected  channels name matches with Broadcast pack table channels name

3) I want display those "Broadcast pack names" in separate samll block/division in that page.

So, can any one please help me out in this.

Thank you.

code:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$sadsdsd = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM AllChannelz");
    $sadsdsd->execute();
    $rowaas = $sadsdsd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $wapakpak=$rowaas[0];
?>


  <script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=0; i<<?php echo $wapakpak ?>; i++) {
    gn = 'sum_m_'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum.toFixed(0);
   document.getElementById('totalitem' ).value = $wapakpak;
}
window.onload=UpdateCost
</script>




<?php
include('connect.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT *  FROM AllChannelz");
        $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
        <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="items[]" value="<?php echo $row['price'] ?>" id="sum_m_<?php echo $i ?>" 
        onclick="UpdateCost()" style="width: 21px;">

            <?php echo $row['ChannelName'] ?>------------<?php echo $row['price'] ?>
        </INPUT><br/>
<?php
    }
?><br>
<?php
$pdoQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";

$pdoResult = $db->query($pdoQuery);

$pdoRowCount = $pdoResult->rowCount();

echo "<h5>Total Count:$pdoRowCount</h5>";

?>
Total Cost : <input type="text" name="sen" id="totalcost" value=""><br/>
Total channels : <input type="text" name="sen" id="totalitem" value=""><br/>
<?php


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this by using JOIN B/W two tables . To implement JOIN B/W these two tables you need to use the concept of foreign key. You can make channel name as foreign key and use Select Query like :

```
Select Broadcastpacknames from broadcastpacks JOIN Allchannellist ON Allchannellist.channelname = broadcastpacks.channelname ORDER BY id
```

Comment: can you please tell me in which table i should make channelname as foreign key.

Comment: make channelname as foreign key in broadcastpacks table